# Using aria-invalid on divs representing input

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am working on a site which asks users to upload items for validation. I would like to make the output of this upload accessible, but I am unclear whether or not it is acceptable to set `aria-invalid` on a `div` when the div represents user input (as opposed to only being valid on input elements).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct to use `aria-invalid` for an element that contains user input if the value of that element has been or will be checked for correctness. The value of the attribute, as defined in the [ARIA spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-invalid), should then be set according to the result of the check, specifically `aria-invalid=true` if the test fails.

The use of this attribute is not limited to form fields. In fact, in them, it is often unnecessary at least in principle if HTML5 checks are performed, since assistive software can have access to its results (though this does not necessarily happen), whereas checks performed with client-side JavaScript only are invisible to assistive software unless you signal their results with ARIA attributes.

A typical scenario is that a `div` element has the `contenteditable=true` attribute and it acts as an advanced user input area, with some checks on its content.

If the `div` element merely *echoes* user input (e.g., user input has been taken via a normal form and a server-side form handler has checked it and sent back a page containing error messages and some copies of user input), then it’s somewhat debatable. It seems that this is a case where ARIA attributes are not meant to be used. Instead, the error messages should clearly indicate the errors and relate them to the user input. There is then no need for `aria-invalid`—unless the `div` element is user-editable and thus acts as an input area, too.